# Finding the length of Fortran allocatable character string

Tags: fortran

How could I find the size of a dynamically allocated object `path` in subroutine `newcase`?

```
  subroutine newcase(path)

  character(:, kind=c_char),
 &     allocatable                     :: path
  integer(kind=c_int)                  :: sizepath

  write(*,*) "Trim Path: ", path, ":"
  this% object = newcase_c(path, sizepath)

  end subroutine newcase
```

The object is allocated when the subroutine is called as shown below:

```
  character(256, kind=c_char)   :: cwd
  character(:, kind=c_char)
 & , allocatable                :: trimpath

  call GETCWD(cwd)
  trimpath = trim(cwd)

  call newcase(trimpath)
```

Comment: With the shown code, the variable 'path' has no size as it is unallocated.

Comment: What function do you use to find the length of character variables, even if they are not allocatable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used `len` to find the length of `path`. Documentation is [here](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-3.4.6/g77/Len-Intrinsic.html).

Comment: `len` will give you the length of the string including trailing blanks.  If you want the length excluding trailing blanks, then use `len_trim`.